# Combinational way of implementing a CAM in verilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, fpga

I'm trying to implement a cache and index lookup memory in SystemVerilog. It's a simple CAM + circular buffer. The interface is:

```
input rst_n;
input clk;
input [WORD_BITS-1:0] inp;
input rd_en;
input wr_en;
output logic [DEPTH_BITS-1:0] index;
output logic index_valid;

reg [WORD_BITS-1:0] buffer[$pow(2, DEPTH_BITS)];
reg [DEPTH_BITS-1:0] next;
```

There's basic async reset code. There's a synchronous block that stores `inp` in buffer and advances `next` whenever `wr_en` is high.

Now I'm trying to come up with an efficient and readable way of finding the index of `inp` when `rd_en` is high. It seems this could be completely combinational except when clocking the result into the `index` output. The way I'm visualizing it in my head is to xor `inp` with all of the buffer locations (it will be fairly small, perhaps 64 entries) then if that is equal to 0 the entry was found. Then a block to arbitrarily choose one of the indices with a 0 value. This is where is differs from a traditional CAM, there could be multiple entries for the same value but I really only need the index of one of those and it doesn't matter which one.

Any thoughts on how to do this in System Verilog (2012)? I know I can loop through all the memory locations synchronously and save a bunch of area but I'd rather it be fast than small. I'm targeting FPGAs. (initially inexpensive Lattice and maybe Xilinx parts) I know a few of the Lattice parts actually have CAM blocks but this is for cases where that isn't available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following up on a suggestion from another forum, the following seems to work well.

```
        always_comb begin
                index_valid = 0;
                for (int i=0; i < 64; i=i+1) begin
                        if (rd_en) begin
                                if (inp == buffer[i]) begin
                                        index = i;
                                        index_valid = 1'b1;
                                end
                        end
                end
        end
```

Comment: I had to hard code the depth as as least Icarus didn't like using a localparam in the for loop for an always_comb.

Comment: This looks good. You probably want to have a default assignment for `index` as well (next to `index_valid = 0;`), even though it is qualified by `index_valid`. This avoid latches in your synthesis.